# Convert an ftrace trace.dat file to CTF format to use with TraceCompass

Tags: ftrace, .ctf, eclipse-tracecompass

I can generate ftrace data either manually (and then `trace-cmd extract` it) or via the convenient trace-cmd(1) front-end utility.

With `trace-cmd`, the output file is `trace.dat` by default; I know I can visually *view* it via kernelshark but would much prefer to use the Trace Compass GUI to do so. AFAIK, TraceCompass uses the `.ctf` file format. My question therefore:

How can I convert the ftrace or `trace.dat` file from `trace-cmd` to `.ctf` format?

(I know there's Q&A on converting perf(1) to CTF).

Answer (score 4):

Trace Compass developer here.

I want to announce Trace Compass natively supports version 6 of the ftrace `trace.dat` format. This is the trace generated by `trace-cmd`. Here is a [video](https://youtu.be/ujLGKdgKBC4) announcing and demoing the feature.

Also, feel free to ask trace compass questions on our [mailing list](https://accounts.eclipse.org/mailing-list/tracecompass-dev) or on the eclipse bugzilla (within trace compass, click on the help menu, report bug...) as we do not check stack overflow very often.

Answer (score 1):

Trace Compass supports the raw textual format of various ftrace plugins. As explained [here](http://archive.eclipse.org/tracecompass.incubator/doc/org.eclipse.tracecompass.incubator.ftrace.doc.user/User-Guide.html), you prior need to run the `trace-cmd report -R` command to get the trace in ASCII format.

Comment: thanks; FYI, it only worked once i went to TC / Tools/Add-ons and selected the 'Trace Compass ftrace (incubation)' and 'Generic Callstack (incubation)' extensions. The FlameGraph 's are useful... (had to get the symbols in); still, cannot see anything in the Resource / Control Flow tabs, nor the func name and params in the usual place.

Answer (score 1):

TraceCompass now supports loading raw binary ftraces. Just use the FTrace add-on from Incubation for Ftrace, it includes raw and text ftrace input support.